# How to replace n numbers of top and bottom values with specific panda column value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame like this,

```
col1    col2
  1      N
  2      N
  3      N
  4      Y
  5      N
  6      N
  7      Y
  8      N
  9      N
  10     N
```

I want to create another data frame from above data frame with this condition, if Y is found in col2, replace N with Y with top and bottom n values of col2. Where I can change the value of n.

for example, if the value of n is 1, then the desired output will be,

```
 col1    col2
  1      N
  2      N
  3      Y
  4      Y
  5      Y
  6      Y
  7      Y
  8      Y
  9      N
  10     N
```

I can do it using for loop iteration but the execution time will be huge. I am looking for pythonic way or pandas shortcut to do it efficiently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One idea is use [`Series.interpolate`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.interpolate.html) with `limit` and `limit_direction='both'` parameters, but working only with numeric, so added `map` and then compare by mapped value for mask, last set values by mask by `loc`:

```
N = 1
m = df['col2'].map({'Y':1}).interpolate(limit=N, limit_direction='both').eq(1)
df.loc[m, 'col2'] = 'Y'
#alternative
#df['col2'] = df['col2'].mask(m, 'Y')
print (df)
   col1 col2
0     1    N
1     2    N
2     3    Y
3     4    Y
4     5    Y
5     6    Y
6     7    Y
7     8    Y
8     9    N
9    10    N
```

Another solution is forward and back filling missing values with `ffill` and `bfill` with `limit` parameter:

```
N = 2
s = df['col2'].mask(df['col2'] == 'N')
df['col2'] = s.ffill(limit=N).fillna(s.bfill(limit=N)).fillna(df['col2'])
print (df)
   col1 col2
0     1    N
1     2    Y
2     3    Y
3     4    Y
4     5    Y
5     6    Y
6     7    Y
7     8    Y
8     9    Y
9    10    N
```